# render intersected pixels differently in the shader

Tags: 2d, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I am a experimenting with shaders and have a question which i cannot find the answer to.

If i have two quads which intersect (not fully) can i render the intersected fragments differently in a fragment shader? 
For example one quad is red and the other one is green (the green one is on top of the red one) and half of the pixels intersect. Can i render the intersected pixels black and the others red/green using a fragment shader (and not with blending)? I am using open gl es 2.0. Thanks!

Comment: Custom blending in GL ES 2.0 can be achieved if GPU supports `EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch` extension: http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt
This way you be able will access fragment color in fragment shader with `gl_LastFragData` variable and decide how to change color.
There are also similar proprietary GL extensions for nVidia's and Apple GPUs.

Comment: just what i needed thanks! please write an answer and i will accept it (if you have any compatibility - for android - reference for the extension would be great)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom blending in GL ES 2.0 can be achieved if GPU supports `EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch` extension. You can read about it here: http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt
This way you will be able to access fragment color in fragment shader with `gl_LastFragData` variable and decide how to change color.

There are also similar proprietary GL extensions for nVidia's (`NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch`) and Apple (`APPLE_shader_framebuffer_fetch`) GPUs.

But please note that this feature is not present in some chips, like ARM's Mali GPUs (and Qualcomm's Adreno AFAIK). On such devices you will need to fall back to some other (quite complicated, I believe) solution.